# Rewrite url, remove category word

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^picxeto\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.picxeto.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^178\.157\.87\.220 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.picxeto.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule wallpapers/(.*)/ wallpapers.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule wallpapers/(.*) wallpapers.php?id=$1

RewriteRule page/(.*)/ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule page/(.*) index.php?page=$1

RewriteRule category/(.*)/ index.php?cat=$1 
RewriteRule category/(.*) index.php?cat=$1

RewriteRule /(.*)/page/(.*)/ index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 
RewriteRule /(.*)/page/(.*) index.php?cat=$1&page=$2

RewriteRule ^dmca$ dmca.php [NC,L]
```

My question is what i have to modify so i can have the url like this:

`picxeto.com/photography` not `picxeto.com/category/photography`

and

`picxeto.com/photography/2` not `picxeto.com/category/photography/page/2`

Help

Comment: you can done with this "WP No Category Base - WPML compatible" plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/

Answer (score 0):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^picxeto\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.picxeto.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^178\.157\.87\.220
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.picxeto.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^wallpapers/([^/]+)/?$ wallpapers.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^category/(.+?)/?$ $1 [R=302,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^dmca/?$ dmca.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Which URL did you that didn't work. Try to provide as much details as possible. Just `Dosent work` kind of comment won't help.

Comment: If i use the htaccess like you suggested the url without category word  picxeto.com/cateogryname dosent work

Comment: As per these rules `picxeto.com/cateogryname` should be internally rewritten to `picxeto.com//index.php?cat=cateogryname`

Answer (score 0):

You can use in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.picxeto.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But if you are using WP , you can use this plugin -> [WP No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/)

Comment: I dont use WP, i use a cms.